# How to check whether the storage account V2 created is having data lake gen2 property or not in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-account, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm very new to Azure and would like to know how can i check an existing Storage account V2 available in resource group is having type Data lake Gen2 or not.

I know the process to create data lake gen 2 by using the option Hierarchical namespace enabled == Data Lake Gen2 while creation.

But how can i check after creation:

1. Any where in portal.
2. Azure CLI - any CLI commands to check

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

On portal, select the storage account and click on `Configuration`. You should be able to see if hierarchical namespace has been enabled on the right hand side as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: As always, this has changed in portal. However, the fact remains, Data Lakes have hierarchical namespace enabled, regular storage doesn't.
At the time of writing, configuration summary in Overview will display hierarchical namespace status.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a storage account is an azure data lake you might use the following query.

```
az resource show --name resourceName --resource-group groupName  --resource-type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"  --query properties.isHnsEnabled
```

If its True then the storage account is an ADL

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the `Az.Storage` PowerShell module. Use `Connect-AzAccount` to connect then run this command:

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -Name StorageAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EnableHierarchicalNamespace
```

If it returns `True` then Data Lake is enabled.

A slightly more abbreviated version of the same command:

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -R ResourceGroupName -N StorageAccountName | select -Exp EnableHierarchicalNamespace
```